# C++ Overload wchar_t assignment operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I have a struct which has a Unicode BSTR string member and looks like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    wchar_t* Bar;
}
```

If I now want to set that string member, I do

```
Foo f;
f.Bar = SysAllocString(L"Hello world");
```

which is kind of verbose.

---

Is there any way I could kind of "overload" the `wchar_t` assignment operator so that I can hide away the `SysAllocString` call and could simply write

```
Foo f;
f.Bar = L"Hello world";
```

where an overloaded assignment operator would take care of the `SysAllocString` call?

I am thinking of something like this (pseudo code):

```
wchar_t* ???::operator=(const wchar_t* rhs)
{
    return SysAllocString(rhs);
}
```

but I don't know what to put instead of the `???` since I am not working on a class.

Comment: It is not possible to overload built-in operators, use `std::string` instead

Comment: @VTT too bad. I will see whether `std::string` is sufficient for my task, considering that I need to work with BSTRs. Thank you for your comment though :)

Comment: I think there are some existing wrappers for `BSTR` as well

Comment: You can overload the assignment operator for your `struct Foo`, so you can write `f = L"Hello world";`

Comment: @mch thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately that won't work for me. I was looking for a solution that works for arbitrary structs without having to do your proposed solution for every struct itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wchar_t` is a builtin type, so you cannot overload an operator on it. That being said, you can either use an `std::wstring` instead of a raw pointer, or define `Foo::operator=(wchar_t*)`:

```
struct Foo
{
    wchar_t* Bar;
    Foo& operator=(wchar_t* bar) { Bar = SysAllocString(bar); return *this; }
}

Foo foo;
foo = L"Hello, World!";
```

---

From comments:

> [U]nfortunately that won't work for me. I was looking for a solution that works for arbitrary structs without having to do your proposed solution for every struct itself

You could define that operator in a base class:

```
struct FooBase
{
    wchar_t* Bar;
    Foo& operator=(wchar_t* bar) { Bar = SysAllocString(bar); return *this; }
}

struct Foo : FooBase { /* whatever */ };
Foo foo;
foo = L"Hello, World!";
```

... or you know, use a type from the standard library :)

Comment: Note that the `operator=` you propose has a memory leak, as you need to `SysFreeString()` the old `Bar` value before you `SysAllocString()` the new `Bar` value.

Comment: Also the default copy-constructor, move-constructor, and destructor all do the wrong thing. The Rule of Five/Zero applies here.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the memory leak you are mentioning is „intentional“ as I intend to call `SysFreeString` on the pointer in C#. The memory will be allocated in C++ and freed in C#.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow nothing in your question mentions C#. But even so, just from C++'s perspective, this class is implemented all kinds of wrong. It needs to follow proper practices while the data is still in the C++ environment. And it is bad practice to have one language take ownership of another language's *internal* data behind its back. COM has very specific rules when it comes to management of dynamic memory, including BSTR. C# follows those rules. You need to follow the rules, too.

Comment: @RemyLebeau *"Nothing in your question mentions C#"* - because it is not important to my actual question, I only added that to clarify that the allocated memory will actually be freed - just not in the provided code sample. *"You need to follow the rules, too"* - allocating a BSTR in C++ and deallocating it in C# is the most suitable way to deal with strings being passed from C++ to C# in my use case, although I am aware of "cleaner" solutions (such as allocating a buffer in C# and filling it in C++). I don't want to offend you or anything; I highly appreciate your input, thank you very much.

Comment: @remi your point about memory management is correct, _but is off-topic_. OP ask a specific question as stated on [ask], and mentioning the memory leak is nice, but should not be the main point of a good answer in my opinion. I answered the specific question with a specific solution, and it's up to OP to use it correctly. You can advise him about it, but if they don't care, they don't care. Period.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly , if it is meant to be a `BSTR` then the member should be:

```
struct Foo
{
    BSTR Bar;
};
```

Even though `BSTR` is a typedef for `wchar_t *`, [a `BSTR` has different semantics to a string of `wchar_t`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/12/erics-complete-guide-to-bstr-semantics/), so this serves as self-documentation.

---

Now, it is normal in C++ programming for OLE to use a class to manage a `BSTR`. You could either use an existing one or roll your own. IMHO it would be better to use one that already exists, although rolling your own can be an interesting learning experience.

I would not recommend  trying to splice in BSTR management functions to `Foo`. This leads to Rule of Five/Zero violations. The BSTR management should be self-contained in its own class and then you can just declare one of these containers as a member of `Foo`.

---

If you are using the Microsoft ATL then you probably have [_bstr_t](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bstr-t-class) and [CComBSTR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccombstr-class) available.

In MinGW-w64, `_bstr_t` is available with `#include <stdio.h>` and then `#include <comutil.h>` and link with `-loleaut32`.

Some other compilers/frameworks have their own wrapper classes for `BSTR`.